# Unexpected behavior of if/else in list comprehension

Tags: python

Why do I get the following behavior? I expect the result to be just 1.

```
In [77]: a = 1

In [78]: [a if a else s for s in [0, 1,0]]
Out[78]: [1, 1, 1]
```

Since `a` is not empty the value in the list should be `a` only.
Here `else` should only be executed when `a` is `None`.

**EDIT**: I want to insert `a` in the list if `a` is not `None`, else insert `s` in the list.

Comment: I think you wanted `[s for s in [0, 1, 0] if s == a]` (or just `... if s]`, as `1` is truth-y and `0` is false-y). It's not clear why you expected the code you posted to have some other output.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Nope. I want to insert a in the list if a is not None, else insert s in the list.

Comment: Can you explain better about what you want?

Comment: `s` has 3 elements so the list comprehension will iterate 3 times, return 1 each time.  This will result in a list with 3 elements...all of them being the value `1`.

Comment: @AniketVij So your result is correct!

Comment: @Kasramvd I have updated the question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Have a look at the latest edit.

Comment: What does "the list" refer to? There is no list, and there is no `s`, there's just `a`, which is 1.

Comment: @jonrsharpe
I am sorry for the confusion, the behavior is correct. I wrote it unexpected, since I was not aware of the syntax. Thanks for iterating over this. I found a solution. :)

Answer (score 2):

That's normal behavior. You're iterating through a list that contains *three* numbers. `if a` is always true. So, `a if a` is executed *three times*. That's why you get three `a`'s added to the list.

Regarding your latest edit:

> I want to insert a in the list if a is not None, else insert s in the list.

Okay, then you do this:

```
res=[]
if a:
    res.append(a)
else: 
    for s in [0,1,0]:
        res.append(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

`a if a else s` evaluates to `a` if a is truthy. `a` never changes, so no matter what you iterate through in the list comprehension, you will get the same thing: a list of `a`s as long as what you are iterating through.

---

Maybe you want this?

```
[a] if a else [0, 1, 0]
```

This expression will evaluate to a list with `a` in it if `a` is truthy, otherwise it'll evaluate to the list you provided.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to put the else inside the brackets.

```
>>> a = 1
>>> [a] if a else [0, 1, 0]
[1]
>>> a = None
>>> [a] if a else [0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 0]
```

Comment: @jonrsharpe true, I didn't even notice that.

Comment: This will give you a generator expression in a list!

Comment: @jonrsharpe ugh, I need to think before I open my keyboard. You should supply your own answer with the comment you deleted, I'd give it an upvote.

Comment: I would, but it does the same thing! It's starting to seem like the OP wants `[1, 0, 1, 0]`, but who knows.

Comment: We may never know, I'm not sure the OP knows what they want.